# How skip SVN commit of branch from trunk

Tags: svn

I usually commit a patch on svn branch then merge it with trunk for synchronization.
But now I have mistakenly commit a patch on trunk.

Now I want to commit same patch on svn branch and then skip this patch information from trunk for synchronization.

I am doing following step:

(1) applied a patch on svn branch and commit it usual way like.

```
svn commit -m "this will resolve some C++.... " branch/*
```

(2) read which revision is need to merge from branch to trunk i.e.
goto trunk local directory and execute following commands:

```
svn mergeinfo branch-repo-path --show-revs eligible

r455818
  ^.................. above command give this revision that need to be merge.
```

(3) tell to trunk that r455818 has already merged it and skip it by using following commands (you sit in trunk directory):

```
svn merge -c 455818 --record-only branch-repo-path
```

*but* executing above command does not show any differences

```
svn diff *
```

and

```
svn st *
```

not show any change.

so where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's perhaps not the answer to your question, but what if you simply undo your commit to the trunk, and then do everything as usual?

```
svn merge -r COMMITTED:PREV .
svn commit -m "Undoing last commit"
```

Comment: You may accept the answer, if it solved your problem.